# как обработать ошибку недоступности сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

как узнать что сервер на socket.io не доступен, если я заключаю свой код, в try catch, то эта конструкция не срабатывает. Событие `socket.on(disconnect, function(){...})` срабатывает, только если сервер выключать во время работы клиента, но если сервер до открытия страницы не был запущен или недоступен, то это событие не срабатывает. Как узнать, что сервер не запущен из клиента?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [документацией](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/), у сокета помимо `disconnect` есть события `error`, `reconnect_error`, `reconnect_failed`. В зависимости от настроек используйте подходящее событие.

Comment: @AlexKrass, все равно не отрабатывается эта ошибка

Comment: Т.е. события `socket.on('error', () => {})`, `socket.on('reconnect_error', () => {})`, `socket.on('reconnect_failed', () => {})` не работают?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, нет, они работаю. Но они не срабатывают, когда сервер изначально недоступен. А срабатывают только, если разрывать соедининие, огда сокет уже подключен

Comment: @max619 `connect_error` попробуй

Answer (score 1):

Существуют несколько событий для обработки.

В твоем случае это `connect_error`.

Попробуй такой код:

```
socket.on('connect_error', function() {
    console.log('Ошибка соединения с сервером. Сервер не доступен!');
});
```